# What is the correct way to declare the jquery variable in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using the below script on my WordPress page to display the read more and less.

```
<p class="countcontent">'.$the_content.'</p>
```

The above p tag is in for condition

```
$data.='<script type="text/javascript">
  
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var maxLength = 390;
var moretxt = "...Read More";
var lesstxt = "Read Less";
  jQuery(".countcontent").each(function() {

    var myStr = jQuery(this).text();
    if (jQuery.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
      var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
      var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, jQuery.trim(myStr).length);
      jQuery(this).empty().html(newStr);
      jQuery(this).append("<span class="more-text">+ removedStr + </span>");
      jQuery(this).append("<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more more">+ moretxt + </a>");
    }
  });

  jQuery(".read-more").click(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass("more")){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("more");
        jQuery(this).text(lesstxt);
        jQuery(this).siblings(".more-text").show();
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this).addClass("more");
        jQuery(this).text(moretxt);
        jQuery(this).siblings(".more-text").hide();
    }

  });
});
</script>';
```

I am getting the issue in this line

```
 jQuery(this).append("<span class="more-text">+ removedStr + </span>");
 jQuery(this).append("<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more more">+ moretxt + </a>");
```

and in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

I have added variables like this `+ removedStr +`  and `+ moretxt +` .Is this the correct way to declare the jquery variable in PHP?

The below code is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotes in your span tags, which is closing the append() method too early, since it is using those same quotes. You must either use double quotes ("") or single quotes ('') in the jQuery method and use the opposite for any HTML code you're appending that contains quotes.

You also forget to end and begin the content with quotes, before and after the JS variable, which will cause the issue of not being able to display the variable contents to the page (it'll be rendered as plain text). Below is what the valid JavaScript should instead look like in your case.

```
jQuery(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');

jQuery(this).append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more more">' + moretxt + '</a>');
```

In the above example, the double quotes have been replaced with single quotes to allow you to use double quotes in the HTML content. The HTML content is surrounded by single quotes to allow for the JavaScript variables to output as they should.

Heads up, remember to escape the single quotes in the jQuery, as in your case, it'll interfere with your PHP tags.

Comment: Give me sometime. let me check the answer

Comment: I tested the above answer. here is the code link https://imgur.com/5qpbbNl and it breaks my WordPress website. I am getting critical error

Comment: @user9437856 You must remember to escape the single quotes. Place a backslash (\) before each single quote (') since PHP is interpreting the single quotes as a closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error with your double-quotes in some of your jQuery. It sees the double quotes, ends the item to append and the next character, > , is unexpected. See this example from the PHP docs on handling strings and quotes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

`// Outputs: Arnold once said: "I'll be back"`
`echo 'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"';`

Your entire $data variable is wrapped in a pair of single quotes. You need to do this in your $data wherever quotes need to be escaped as you alternate their use, for example:

```
$data .= '<script type="text/javascript">
  ...
    jQuery(this).append(\'<span class="more-text">+ removedStr + </span>\');
  ...
```

Quick Edit: The variables you are trying to use look correct, I just noticed your syntax issues is probably what you are hung up on.

Comment: I tested your answer, I am still getting the error Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: Reference Austin's answer and comments. Like I said, you need to escape any of the single quotes inside of the $data PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery in WordPress, consider the following.

```
jQuery(function($){
  var maxLength = 390;
  var moretxt = "...Read More";
  var lesstxt = "Read Less";
  $(".countcontent").each(function() {
    var myStr = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (myStr.length > maxLength) {
      var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
      var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, myStr.length);
      $(this).empty().html(newStr);
      $(this).append("<span class='more-text'>" + removedStr + "</span>");
      $(this).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='read-more more'>" + moretxt + "</a>");
    }
  });

  $(".read-more").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("more")){
      $(this).removeClass("more");
      $(this).text(lesstxt);
      $(this).siblings(".more-text").show();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("more");
      $(this).text(moretxt);
      $(this).siblings(".more-text").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, when using Double Quotes (`"`), you will need to use Single Quotes (`'`) to be included in the String. There were two points where this was an issue in your SPAN and your A strings. Also you were using the `+` operator without  closing the String wrappers.

When you use `jQuery(function(){});`, this is shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});`. See More: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

If you want to use a shorthand and ensure it does not conflict with other libraries, take a look here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: I tested the above answer. it breaks my WordPress website. I am getting a critical error

Comment: Can you check this code..https://imgur.com/undefined   is there any issue with this because I am getting 0.

Comment: @user9437856 What error do you see in Console? Your link did not work.

Comment: https://imgur.com/rCMSt4S please check this link. I am not getting any error in the console even my each function not calling

Comment: @user9437856 you do not need to escape the Single Quotes the way you did. Remove the Backslash from before the quotes. You only need to escape Quotes if the they are wrapped by the same type. E.G.: `var string = "<span class=\"my-class\">foo</span>";`

Comment: I also tried your code but my website goes down.

Comment: I tried below code and it's wokring.  jQuery(this).append("<span class=\"more-text\">"+ removedStr +"</span>");
jQuery(this).append("<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"read-more more\">Read more</a>");